# Scipy Integration to calculate E(X) of distributions available in scipy stats

Tags: scipy, normal-distribution, numerical-integration, scipy.stats

Hi can anybody help me with fixing this code, thanks in advance

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
import math
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

lognorm_mu = 17.79
lognorm_sigma = 0.81

def integrand(x):
    return stats.lognorm.pdf(x, s= lognorm_sigma, scale=math.exp(lognorm_mu)) * x
```

i was expecting the result to be:

```
print(math.exp(lognorm_mu + lognorm_sigma ** 2 / 2)) ==> 73887187.89137973
```

but instead i am getting this output:

```
print(quad(integrand2,-np.inf,np.inf)[0]) =-> 8.373817736767941e-43
```

How can i edit my integrand to be doing integrate(xf(x)dx, -inf, +inf)? what about if i am going to do integrate(x^2f(x)dx, -inf, +inf)?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for the `.expect` method : `norm.expect(lambda x : x**2)`  etc

Comment: if I do stats.lognorm.expect(args=(0.81,), scale=math.exp(17.79), lb=-np.inf, ub=np.inf), i am still not getting my expected output, I still got 8.373817736767941e-43 ....

Comment: I am trying to make sense of the differences between the three lines here:
stats.lognorm.stats(s=0.81, scale=math.exp(17.79), moments='m')
array(73887187.89137967)

stats.lognorm.expect(args=(0.81,),scale=math.exp(17.79))
8.373817736767941e-43

stats.lognorm.mean(s=0.81, scale=math.exp(17.79))
73887187.89137967